# Enviar mensajes a Usuarios con información sensible

Tags: discusión

El día de hoy estaba en el sitio de manera habitual y me topé con esta pregunta [¿Como hacer que el cuerpo del juego snake siga la cabeza, añadiendo elementos a una lista? (en consola)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11425/como-hacer-que-el-cuerpo-del-juego-snake-siga-la-cabeza-a%C3%B1adiendo-elementos-a#11425) El dueño del post le comenta a una de las personas que ha brindado una respuesta, que si le puede dar su correo para hablar mejor ya que tiene algunas dudas.

Entiendo que existen herramientas como el chat, que nos sirven de ayuda en estos momentos, pero mis dudas son las siguientes ¿Esta permitido el envío de información sensible como email, número telefónico o algo similar en una pregunta/respuesta? ¿En estos casos se debe flagear el comentario, para que sea eliminado? o en su defecto ¿Cual sería la forma de abordar comentarios de este tipo?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hay una pregunta muy similar y su respuesta en el sitio Meta StackExchange bajo la pregunta [¿Existe una manera de enviar mensajes personales a un usuario?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), donde el concenso para todos los sitios es **no**. **Bajo ninguna circunstancia debemos promover la solicitud de información personal ni de contacto de un usuario** en las publicaciones: preguntas, respuestas, comentarios. Los sitios de StackExchange promueven **el aprendizaje de la comunidad mediante preguntas y respuestas**, no es una red social.

StackExchange provee las [salas de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) donde [los usuarios con 20 de reputación o más](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) pueden comunicarse de manera más coloquial, pueden crear salas para comunicarse de manera más personal e incluso se pueden crear salas de chat a partir de respuestas para evitar discusiones en comentarios. Los mensajes de chat son públicos, cualquier persona los puede ver, de manera que no existen mensajes *privados* entre usuarios.

Considera que, como usuario, eres libre de colocar tu información personal y de contacto en tu perfil. El perfil es un espacio libre donde puedes compartir esta información de manera pública. Si brindas tu correo, es probable que algunas personas te contacten por allí, pero StackExchange no es responsable de las consecuencias de este tipo de acciones.

Answer (score 3):

Pues no creo que sea permitido, y no creo que deba permitirse, debido a que cualquier problema o cualquier cosa que ocurra, no dirán que fue por que, si no que señalaran a la comunidad por permitir este tipo de cosas, como es el caso de envío de información sensible.

Aunque se podría suponer que las personas llegan a a comunidad con la intención de aprender y aportar, en esos casos pues que se integren a la o las salas de chat.